# Punch through layer below in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have read that Opacity Mask is used for such task. However did not manage to make it work properly. Is there any other way to punch through layers?

[image]

[Vector File](https://we.tl/t-lzoGHtawp2)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a separate layer for the moustache.

Try this:

1. Select and Cut the moustache, Select Layer 1, then Paste in Place.
2. Target Layer 1 in the layers panel
3. Use the Shape Builder tool, hold down the Alt key, and drag over the line you want to delete.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. However I want to keep parts of image in separate layers that it is easier to manipulate image.

Comment: @CreekDrop The reason I suggested this method is because AFAIK it's not possible to have an opacity mask punch through two layers at the same time. The mask has to be on the same layer that it is applied to.  In effect you would have a moveable moustache on layer 2, but the mask would need to be applied to layer 1. If you moved the moustache, you'd then need to move the mask separately. Of course this may work for you, but it wouldn't be easy to manipulate.  Also note that you did ask for "any other way", and that's why I suggested it.